# jquery mobile windows phone 7 back button crash

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create a phonegap + jquery mobile app for Windows Phone 7.1.

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.2, cordova.2.7.0, jquery 1.9.1

the very same code, runs fluently on android, however is stuck on WP.

I have removed all JS functionality, and tried just the jquery mobile navigation. Whenever I navigate to a page, and click phones back button, it stays there with the loading sign, and never finishes.

Any ideas what could cause the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to run separate, that html page in IE 9 or later ?

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet for the navigation... I am trying to resolve something to an end.

Comment: I have removed all the JS code. There are only divs and anchor links which refer to other divs with data-role="page"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<div data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header"><h3> Header </h3> </div>
    <div data-role="content" >    
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button">Page 2</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header"><h3> Header </h3> </div>
    <div data-role="content" >    
        <a href="javascript:;" data-rel="back" data-role="button" >Back</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your effort very much. Unfortunately, it did not work.